# VB.NET SendMessage to Another Form in Project

Tags: vb.net, forms, project, sendmessage, sendkeys

I have a 3 form project.

I want form3 to use sendmessage to form2 but i can't ever get it to work.
If it makes any difference form2 has a flash object on it (a game particularly) i want to send those keys to it.

here is a bit of what i have and i don't know why it doesn't work:

```
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                         (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpwindowname As String) As IntPtr
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                 (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, Window)
    SendMessage(destination, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.Down, 0)

End Sub
```

To clarify window is a string which holds the form2.text.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a simple method in form2 and then when keydown is used in form3 call that method.

Let's say a key is press in form3 so you have the code:

```
    Private Sub Form3_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

       If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Down) Then
           Form2.KeyIsPress()
       End If

    End Sub
```

So, in your Form2 you add the method KeyIsPress()

```
Public Sub KeyIsPress()

    MessageBox.Show("Key Down is Press")

End Sub
```

I assume that both forms (i.e. Form2 and Form3) are running.

Comment: I used keys.down for a test. And yes they are both open at the same time. However i want to send a string of keys. `1k for example. from from3 to form2

Comment: what are exactly this 'string of keys'?

Comment: basically hot keys for a game. ` targets, 1 uses item in first slot. I used sendkeys for a while like this SendKeys.Send("`1`2`3k"), but the window has to be infocus, i want to make something were the window does not have to be in focus

Comment: Are you saying you are sending multiple keys (say number 1, number 2 and number 3) at one time from form3 to form2 using SendKeys.Send() and that form3 has to be focus all the time while displaying the changes on form2?

Comment: Yes! But i don't want to use SendKeys i want to be able to send the keys to the form without it being focused. (sendmessage)